# Code runs an order of magnitude faster when optimizations enabled. Am I missing something?

Tags: c, performance, compiler-optimization

As far as my (limited) knowledge of optimization goes, I always thought that compiler optimizations don't matter *that much.* I mean, we can surely gain quite a few percents (maybe 0...100% as a very rough first thoughtproximation) of time by using registers instead of memory and unrolling loops, but **the fundamental factor that constrains the performance of code is really the choice of algorithms.**

---

I've recently started a pet project - a small interpreted scripting language. It compiles to bytecode and executes it using a virtual machine. For the sake of easy debugging, profiling and testing, first I've naturally compiled the code with the `-O0 -g` flags of `gcc` (and `clang`), then with `-O2`. I've then `time`'d a small program running on the VM, which basically does this (pseudo-code, I'm not showing you the actual syntax until the project goes public):

```
i = 1
sum = 0

while (i < 10000000) {
    sum = (sum + i * i) mod 1000000
    i++
}

print sum
```

This translates roughly to the following pseudo-assembly:

```
load r0, 0   # sum = 0
load r1, 1   # i = 1
load r2, 1000000
load r3, 10000000

loop:
mul  r4, r1, r1 # i * i
add  r0, r0, r4 # sum += i * i
mod  r0, r0, r2 # sum %= 1000000
inc  r1
gt   r5, r1, r3 # if i > 10000000
jz   r5, loop   # then don't goto loop

ret  r0
```

So basically, this is a tight loop with 10000000 iterations. `time` reports that it runs for 0.47...0.52 seconds when compiled with `-O2`, in 1.51...1.74 seconds when compiled with `-O0 -g` and in 3.16...3.47 seconds when profiling (`-pg`) is enabled as well.

As you can see, there's a 7-fold difference between the fastest and slowest execution time.

This in itself is not *that* surprising, because I've known that additional debugging information and the lack of small optimizations does indeed make code run slower, but now comes the interesting part. In order to have a more realistic perception of what actually happens, I've played the same game with Lua 5.2. Fiddling around with the `Makefile`, I've found that the very same Lua program:

```
local sum = 0

for i = 1, 10000000 do
    sum = (sum + i * i) % 1000000
end

print(sum)
```

runs in about 0.8...0.87 seconds when Lua is compiled with `-O0 -g -pg`, and in 0.39...0.43 seconds when only `-O2` is enabled.

So my code seems to have a 7x speed boost when the optimizer performs tricky fix-ups on it, whereas the Lua reference implementation seems to benefit from these improvements much less.

Now my questions are:

1. **Any idea why this happens?** I suspect that the primary reason is that the creators of Lua are smarter than me and know better what the compiler and their VM is doing.
2. I've also caught myself thinking "well this must be premature optimization; let me just pass it to the optimizer, it will do the job anyway" several times. These include one-line static functions called in the implementation of almost every VM instruction (I thought that they will be inlined when necessary anyway), the use of various complex expressions (sometimes with not-so-easy-to-predict side effects) that can be simplified, though. **Does this attitude of mine count too?** (And is it the right attitude, by the way?)
3. And anyway, **should I worry about this phenomenon at all?** My code runs 1.5 times slower than Lua, after all - and that's pretty good (at least it's good enough for me). Should I try to improve the performance of the debug build just because not doing so indicates that I lack intimate knowledge of my own code? Or may I just forget about it completely as far as the release (optimized) build is fast enough?

<sub>(If this question would be a better fit for Prog.SE or CodeReview, let me know and I'll migrate it.)</sub>

Comment: 7x isn't quite an order of magnitude faster in out decimal-centric world.

Comment: Have you looked to assembly code for your loop with -O0 and -O2 flags? It would explain a lot (I think that gcc doesn't even use registers aggressively with -O0). As for me, I wouldn't worry much about speed of code compiled without optimization. Regarding inlining: it depends on compiler, and I agree with you: thinking of it is premature optimization, profile your final code and play with inlining then.

Comment: It's difficult to say without a lot more detail. I also suspect your point #1 is relevant. The compiler will do things such as move loop invariants out of loops, eliminate dead code, reorder statements for better cache coherency and memory timing, etc. It is possible (even likely) that the creators of Lua are very aware of these effects and keep them in mind with their own VM.

Comment: To be clear, you have an interpreter written in C, and the bytecode being interpreted is the same in any case? And that bytecode is roughly as low-level as your "equivalent pseudo-assembly", in particular with instructions specialized for integer arithmetic?

Comment: Have you read the stuff from Agner Fog? http://www.agner.org/optimize/

Comment: @CharlesBailey Well I rounded :P The emphasis is on that instead of the 1.xxx improvement I expected, I've got a 7-fold difference.

Comment: @Inspired I have yet to do that since it is a lot of assembler (well, for me anyway, I'm not great at assembly), but I definitively will (of course, that answers a fair amount of questions but points #2 and #3 still stand.)

Comment: @ChrisHayes Yes, that's what I thought too.

Comment: @delnan Exactly, an interpreter written in C, the bytecode is hand-written by me for now (because I haven't finished the compiler yet) and it is the exact same code each time it runs. Also, the bytecode is quite low-level: I have instructions with 3 operands for arithmetic, comparisons, etc.

Comment: @Macmade I've never come across that site, it's very useful, thanks!

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry, I meant assembly code of the loop written in C, it should be quite small. Well, I've just checked that: with -O0 gcc doesn't even store `i` in a register, it loads it every time from stack.

Comment: @Inspired There's really no such thing as "the assembly of the loop". The loop is not written in C.

Comment: @H2CO3 Of course. Sorry for not making myself clear. I just wanted to show how compiler worked in -O0 and why it could be so slower, so I've rewritten your loop in C.

Comment: You are competing with a VM implementation that's been around for 20 years.  Written in an era and a country where good C compilers were not yet available.  So the C code was hand-tuned to be fast.  It stands to reason that it will benefit less from a good C code optimizer.

Comment: The choice of algorithms is only one side of the story. A better time complexity really only promises a better time once the input gets "big enough"; sometimes "big enough" is small, sometimes it's several orders of magnitude bigger than any input you'll ever actually get, sometimes it's so big that you'd need more RAM cells than there are atoms in our galaxy.

Comment: @HansPassant That seems to constitute an answer, indeed.

Comment: @harold Of course, I'm well aware of that fact. This example (10 million iterations) seems to be a big enough test case, doesn't it?

Comment: @H2CO3 well it doesn't really matter how big it was, you're not comparing it with anything else. You're comparing the same algorithm with itself, with a different implementation. It's not like there's a rule that says that that can't matter. Quite the contrary - you could make an implementation arbitrarily bad, so that factor can be whatever you want it to be.

Comment: @harold It was exactly my goal with comparing the two implementations. And in fact, before this experiment, I've had another implementation (one that wasn't based on a bytecode interpreter), and that was literally a hundred times slower. So IMHO this does prove that choosing the right algorithm matters.)

Comment: But it was the same algorithm. You've proven that the implementation matters.

Comment: @harold No, I am talking about a different algorithm. (One which I haven't mentioned in my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your assertion that the algorithm is more important than the optimizations is generally true, but the same algorithm can be coded to make best or worst use of the platform you are executing on, so optimizations should always be considered... just avoid optimising prematurely, instead of avoiding optimising at all.

Next, remember that debug builds add a lot of overhead. Much more than merely disabling optimisation. To see what the optimiser is doing, use a release build with optimizations disabled.

The differences between Lua and your language will be due to the efficiency of your bytecode interpreter. A tiny inefficiency in here will have a massive effect on the speed of execution of such a large loop. you might also be able to add optimizations such as:

- using "registers" to hold the variables used within the loop (in the byte code, load the variable into slot 1, then use new instructions that multiply and mod the slots using a simple array index rather than a named variable, then write the final value of the slot back to the variable at the end of the loop.
- detecting that the loop executes a constant number of times, perhaps there is a way you can express this in byecode so that the loop variable and logic is executed by native code rather than by interpreting bytecode. You can obviously add special cases for lots of situations, so the trick here is to work out the most common constructs and optimise those first, to get the biggest bang for your buck.

Lastly, don't worry about the efficiency of your debug code. When you have a working interpreter, then you can profile a release build to look for areas that you can improve. Doing this prematurely will not help, as there is no point optimising partially complete code and then finding out that it needs to be changed to support a new feature. And it's only when you have a working system that you can start writing typical scripts that will exercise your interpreter in a realistic manner - you may find that optimising a loop like the example above yields no benefit in day to day scripts.

Comment: Definitely, I don't want to "avoid optimizations at all", your last paragraph is the real answer I think. Also, I don't use named variables. If you look at the "assembly" I posted, it's easy to deduce that I already use a register machine. Detecting constant iteration counts is a good idea, though.